# As compared to android, does it cost money to develop for windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-8, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have been reading a number of blogs on the subject. But now I am left with a number of sometimes contradictory information. I hope this community can present me the truth on the matter.

WHAT I HAVE:

I own a mac osx mountain lion. I also own a pc, which I bought in November 2008, that's running both Windows Vista and Ubuntu.

COMPARISON:

If **I** decide to develop for android right now, **I** can get everything I need for free:

- I can get the IDE (eclipse) for free
- I can get the android sdk for free
- I can get the emulators for free
- I only have to pay a $25 lifetime fee if I decide to publish on the Google Play Store
- No computer to buy; no OS to buy; no IDE to buy; nothing to buy.

Can someone please tell me: Is it the same for windows 8 development? With my existing computers, would it be cost free to develop for windows 8? If not, what do I need to buy. Please no iffy info, I am looking for decisive information. One blog, for example, talks about a 30 day free-trial of the Windows 8 OS: This is clearly not free now is it?

Also is developing for windows phone the same as developing for windows 8? Some blogs treat the two as equivalent. What's the reality?

- A: All windows phone apps work on windows 8?
- B: All windows 8 apps work on windows phone?
- C: Both A and B

How about windows 7? Is there a relationship there with windows phones?

Note: I understand the details may make this seem like a number of questions in one; but I had to include the details. The question, however, is one: does it cost money to develop for windows based on the criteria I present?

Comment: There is nothing "lifetime" about it. Lifetime would imply that it is a fee a developer would pay "once in a lifetime", and that would be it, they would never again during their life need to pay said fee. Google lied to you about this. What they really meant was "one time fee until your account goes inactive after 180 days". Let me remind you, 180 days is EXTREMELY opposite of "Lifetime". A “bait and switch” is a scam to mislead developers, whereby Google advertises an appealing but ingenuine offer to sell a service that Google does not actually intend to honor (i.e. "Lifetime").

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To develop Windows Store/Modern UI applications for Windows 8 you need a computer running the Windows 8 OS.

For Windows Phone 8 development you specifically need Windows 8 Professional 64-bit.

Windows 8 is not free, but there is a [90-day evaluation for developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/evalcenter/jj554510.aspx) that you can download free.  Since you have a Vista license you should also be able to upgrade that to Windows 8, but again that is not free (just as OSX upgrades are not, IIRC).

[Visual Studio Express versions](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2012-express) are FREE and available for both Windows 8 and Windows Phone development (they *are* different platforms, but with some overlap in terms of code reuse).

To publish to the Windows Store (Windows 8 apps) there is a $49 annual account fee.  For the Windows Phone Store, it's a separate account that has a $99 annual fee.

- If you are a student and join [DreamSpark](http://dreamspark.com), both of these fees are waived.
- If you are a [MSDN subscriber](http://msdn.microsoft.com), likewise these fees are waived.
- An MSDN subscription is part of the [BizSpark program for startups](http://bizspark.com) as well, so if you qualify there, you would get free store accounts as well as access to Windows 8.

With Windows 7 you would only be able to develop applications for the Windows Phone 7 platform, so given the setup you've described there's no advantage in going to 7 versus 8.  When you build Windows Phone applications with Windows 8 development tools you will still be able to target Windows Phone 7 devices in addition to the newer Windows Phone 8 devices.

Do keep in mind that Microsoft is always running promotions and incentives in various markets (in the US, for instance, there is the [Keep the Cash](http://aka.ms/keepthecash) program where you can get $100 for up to 10 apps you publish in the Windows Store, and another $1000 for Windows Phone applications, - more than offsetting costs to get up and running)!

Likewise, there are Microsoft audience evangelists across the world whose role it is to help you get started and be a successful app publisher on the platform.  Do reach out to your local rep as he or she may can provide additional guidance and make you aware of offers/incentives that may help you to get started. If you don't know how to reach him or her, please send me a note via my profile and I will connect you.

Comment: Don't forget BizSpark!

Comment: yes good point, BizSpark gives you MSDN, but I'll emend to call it out specifically

Comment: I can't find a way to contact you private. I even went on your blog but the send button for email is not working.

Comment: hmmm, will check into blog... joneil AT Microsoft DOT com

Comment: Thanks! I email you at 2:27pm Pacific Standard Time

Comment: It seems like Microsoft have revised their pricing and now it's one time 19$ for individuals and 99$ for a company. If that is true,  would you consider updating your post?

Answer (score 6):

It is and it is not free, *depends on how you look at it.*

To develop apps for Windows 8 you need a proper **Windows 8 license**. Technically, if you don't buy a new computer or a tablet these days, then you need to buy Windows 8 OS and install it on your existing machine to be able to start developing. That costs money, of course.

Once you buy Windows 8, **the development tools for developing apps are free** in Express versions, which are perfectly enough for you to develop apps.

Comparing to Android, you would probably want to buy an Android device to test your apps before you publish them. Technically speaking, **by having the Windows 8 OS you have the device and emulator at the same time**, so there you won't have any new hardware costs.

Price of the annual subscription **is around 50 USD if you're an individual**, and around 99 USD if you're a company. Not sure about your status, but if you're a student, you can **get an annual subscription for both Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8 development over Dreamspark for free**. If you're an MSDN subscriber, you also get the free annual subscriptions. You might even have access to Windows 8 through MSDN and/or Dreamspark Premium.

**Regarding the Windows Phone:**

- Currently, the Windows Phone apps you develop will work only inside
  Windows Phone emulators on Windows 8
- Currently, Windows 8 apps don't work on Windows Phone

The development for those two platform has many similarities, so you can reuse some code from you Windows 8 app in your Windows Phone 8 app and vice versa by either using portable libraries or simply by changing some things.

**On Windows 7 you can develop Windows Phone 7 apps**

I think you need to decide for yourself. It seems to me that you're trying to make a long term decisions but have difficulties understanding the simple differences between Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8.

Also, before deciding, have in mind the size of the platforms.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. +1. The answers are all great. But I could only pick one.

Answer (score 5):

There are two different things you can target if you're going to develop for Windows 8.  You can target the desktop or you can target WinRT.  Windows Phone 8 is a slightly different animal.

To target the desktop you don't need Windows 8 and you can use Visual Studio express, so targeting the desktop is free.

To develop for WinRT (the tablet interface for Windows 8) you need to have Windows 8 (previous versions of the OS don't support targeting WinRT).  You also need VS, but again, you can use the express version, so there is no require costs.  Finally, you need to register as a developer for the Windows App Store.  See pricing on there [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj863494.aspx).  If you meet the requirements, you can get a [BizSpark Account](http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/default.aspx) and get all the needed things to develop for WinRT for free (Windows 8, Appstore account and even VS Pro).

Developing for Windows 8 phone is slightly different.  The core is most the same as for WinRT, but the UI is different, so you can share a lot of non-UI code with a WinRT app, but will need to have a separate UI.  Costs for this are similar to that of WinRT with the same caveats.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. +1. The answers are all great. But I could only pick one.